# how to select all full cells and copy into other doc vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select all of the filled cells in a different excel document and paste it into a different excel document but I keep getting an error message.

```
Worksheets("FOO").Range("H:H").Formula = dib.Worksheets("GOO").Range(Cells
(1, 1), Cells(rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Formula
```

Comment: Qualify `Cells()` with the workbook/worksheet, just like you did with the Sheet.

Comment: When I do Cells("B:B") it selects all of the cells empty and filled, is there another way to format it to just get the filled cells?

Comment: Try `... = dib.Worksheets("GOO").Range(dib.Worksheets("GOO").Cells
(1, 1), dib.Worksheets("GOO").Cells(rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Formula`

Comment: I'm still getting the empty cells, is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`IF i understood your question you can try this code and after you can copy the result in other file(you have to add another code).

```
Dim r, c, count, numRows, numCols As Integer

numRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count ' number rows
numCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count ' number columns
count = 1

For c = 1 To numCols
count = 1
    For r = 1 To numRows

        If (Cells(r, c) <> "") Then

            'prendo il dato e lo metto nell'altro foglio
            With Sheets("Destination")'name second sheet where i get final result

               'copy data into destination sheet
               .Cells(count, c) = Cells(r, c)
                count = count + 1
            End With            
        End If        
    Next r    
Next c
```